# flash and jquery menu problem

Tags: jquery, flash, menu

i am using jquery drop down menu and under the menu i am using flash banner, i am using flash with swfobject_2_2

my code is like this

```
        <ul id="jsddm">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#">products</a>
<ul><li><a href="1.html">product 1</a></li>
<li><a href="2.html">product 2</a></li>
<li><a href="accessories.html">Accessories</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="contacts.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and for flash

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
    </script>
        <div id="myContent">
        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
    </div>
```

the problem i am facing is

sub menu goes under flash menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the flash movie object embed property **wmode** to **transparent** or **opaque**

ie:
(important parts in bold)

**var params = {

wmode: "transparent",

};**

swfobject.embedSWF("someswf.swf", "flashcontent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.124", "whereverthisis/expressInstall.swf", **null, params**);

Comment: its working fine with Internet explorer but not working with Firefox... :(

Comment: It should work on all browsers? (I have an example) 
You may have to try giving the sub menus a z-index depending the the CSS used to hide/show them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **wmode** property:

Check this:

```
http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=e5141
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no this is not solution cause i i am also using flash with swfobject to diable internet explorer click to active message...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a menu that is compatible with this kid of situation. Usually the solution is to put an iframe under the menu (yeah it's ugly, but IE needs that).

I'd recommend the Chrome menu since I've used it a lot. It's easily customizable and really nice : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chrome/index.htm

Without having to do all that, playing with the flash wmode and css z-index sometime fix the problem.